# SFSafariViewController and handoff

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller, handoff

In the app that I'm working on whenever I present a SFSafariViewController it doesn't show the handoff icon on my Mac. Although it does appear for other apps that use that controller.

Are there any additional steps needed to get this to work?